# php undefined property of an object

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm sure this is more simple than I'm making it.

The error that I get...

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\Database\Connection::$config [... line 73]
```

The code on line 73...

```
Line 72: debug($conn);
Line 73: debug($conn->config);
```

Here's what $conn equals

```
$conn = object(Cake\Database\Connection) {

    'config' => [
        'password' => '*****',
        'username' => '*****',
        'host' => '*****',
        'database' => '*****',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres',
        'persistent' => false,
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    ],
}
```

Anyone know why $conn->config isn't the right syntax?

Comment: Is `config` a public variable in the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public property named `$config` only a protected `$_config` in the database connection class in Cake (http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Database.Connection.html).

With the the database connection in Cake you must use the public function `config()` to get the configuration array.

```
 $config = $conn->config();
```

I don't know what `debug()` does, but it's not returning a detailed representation of the properties of the object as would `var_dump` or as you could get from reflection.  Don't rely on it to learn the interface of an object/class.